# Why won't this jQuery script work?

Tags: jquery

I've tried to make a simple jQuery script that removes/hides a form once it's submit button has been pressed.

Here's the HTML and jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input").click(function(){
  $("#form1").hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <form action="/database.php" method="POST" id="form1">
  <div class="input">
   <p>Enter player names, separated by commas:</p>
   <input type="text" name="input_players">
  </div>

  <div class="input">
   <p>Enter game name:</p>
   <input type="text" name="input_game">
  </div>

  <div class="submit">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're loading your script before jQuery gets loaded. You can't use a library that hasn't arrived yet. Wouldn't be an issue if you didn't rely on unnecessary dependencies like jQuery.

Comment: You need to add a preventdefault as you are submitting that form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this where your script uses jQuery, but your script is loaded before jQuery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to switch the order so that jquery is loaded first, and available for you to use in your script when it is loaded afterwards.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume main.js has the JS code OP included in the question? A reasonable assumption because OP hasn't indicated otherwise, but an assumption nevertheless.

Comment: main.js did indeed have the JS code in it and placing jQuery first worked for me, thanks

Comment: @Vasan - Yeah, he provided the entire HTML document, and it only linked to one other script, seems pretty logical to assume the JS code he posted was the one JS file linked to.

Answer (score 1):

$("input") means "all elements of type input".
So when pressing any of the form's elements it is hidden.
To achieve what you want, change it to:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

at the end of the body, to make sure jquery (used by this script) has loaded. Or better, execute it with a callback when `$(document ).ready()` event is fired.

Right now you hide the entire form when it is clicked because you intercept the fired click event. The selector selects all the input items. You have 3.

Turn into

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#form1").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you submit the form to `"/database.php"` that don't exist. For test you can disable the form submit with `preventDefault` or redirect to a randow URL, like `https://stackoverflow.com`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(e){
  $("#form1").hide();
                e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    test
 <form action="https://stackoverflow.com" method="POST" id="form1">
  <div class="input">
   <p>Enter player names, separated by commas:</p>
   <input type="text" name="input_players">
  </div>

  <div class="input">
   <p>Enter game name:</p>
   <input type="text" name="input_game">
  </div>

  <div class="submit">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: With your code the form will hide in any click on input's (not only the button), a changed `$("input")` to `$("submit")` to correct this.

Comment: How do you know the php doesn't exist?

Comment: @Vasan because the code works in the first place (if you click in submit right away), only problem is that in the snippet this file naturally don't exist (and of course, any click in the inputs will hide the form but its another problem).

Comment: The file doesn't exist on SO. On OP's server, it would. When you click submit on this page it is submitting to SO, not OP's server.